# if choose this option and this option change to 3 option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table rows (this is not real, this is only example for simple it):
id, cat, company, device.
for example some recordes:
1, computer, samsung, ativ
2, computer, lg, blabla
3, phones, samsung, s6
4, phones, sony, z5
 
I want that if I choose category (computer for example) this will open only the company that they have computer, In addition, when the user select the second select, this will give the option that remain.
I found here the answer for the first select but for the second I did find.
I dont want to do "if ..., if ..." because this is need to be from the database and automatic.
This is the example that i did:
http://jsfiddle.net/e464etcq/

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="1">phones</option>
  <option value="2">computers</option>  
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="reason" name="reason">
    <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="1" class="1">samsung</option>
  <option value="2" class="1">lg</option>
  <option value="3" class="2">samsung</option>
  <option value="3" class="2">sony</option>

</select>
<input type="text" id="billing">
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var backupShipStates = $("#reason").html();
    $("#type").change(function() {
        var country = $(this).val();
        var options = $(backupShipStates).filter(function() {
        return !$(this).attr("class") || $(this).attr("class") == country; });
        $("#reason").html(options);
    });
});
```

do you have any suggition how to do it?
Thank you,
Omry.

Comment: How is this related to `php`? Also I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understand you, you could add a new `change event` to handle when the second select is changed.

So your code would be:

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="">בחר</option>
  <option value="1">phones</option>
  <option value="2">computers</option>  
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="reason" name="reason">
  <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="1" class="1">samsung</option>
  <option value="2" class="1">lg</option>
  <option value="3" class="2">samsung</option>
  <option value="3" class="2">sony</option> 
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="third" name="third">
    <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="1" class="1">Option3.1</option>
  <option value="2" class="1">Option3.2</option>
  <option value="3" class="2">Option3.3</option>
  <option value="3" class="2">Option3.4</option>

</select>
<input type="text" id="billing">
```

jQuery

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    var backupShipStates = $("#reason").html();
    var backupOption3 = $("#third").html();
    $("#type").change(function() {
        var country = $(this).val();
        var options = $(backupShipStates).filter(function() {
        return !$(this).attr("class") || $(this).attr("class") == country; });
        $("#reason").html(options);
    });
    $("#reason").change(function(){
        var reason = $(this).val();
        var options = $(backupOption3).filter(function() {
                    return !$(this).attr("class") || $(this).attr("class") == reason; });
        $("#third").html(options);
    });
});
```

Here is not necessary PHP.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but this is not solve my problem.. I dont need to copy the text from reason to billing, I need to write 3ed word there... thank you!